# How to write a SQL Server scalar function to calculate the sum?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sum, sql-function

I'm having an issue with SQL Server 2008, I want to write a function that returns the sum of a specific column, the code goes like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIssuesSum](@i int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IssueSum int

    SELECT SUM (@IssueSum = Quantity) 
    FROM Issue

    RETURN @IssueSum

END
```

When I try to execute it, SQL Server 2008 throws this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetIssuesSum, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIssuesSum](@i int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IssueSum int

    SELECT @IssueSum = SUM(Quantity) 
    FROM Issue

    RETURN @IssueSum
END
```

You need to assign the `SUM(Quantity)` to your SQL variable - not have the SQL variable inside the `SUM()` expression

Comment: thank you so much, this is the right answer, I will choose it as accepted answer after some minutes :) thanks again

Comment: Thanks. Is the parameter `i` as declared as `@i int` ever used in the definition of the function? If not, what is the purpose of defining a parameter which is not going to be used?